# Access to Details of each item in groupby

Tags: c#, database, linq, group-by

I have a large database and I need to groupby to find the count of each `Customer`. this is my query:

```
var statisticList = (from item in Connection.DBConnection.TBStatistics
                                 where item.Date >= startDate && item.Date <= endDate
                                 group item by item.Customer into grp
                                 where grp.Count() > 1
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Customer = grp.Key,
                                     Count = grp.Count(),
                                 }).ToList();
```

Each Customer have some other properties like `Id`, `PhoneNumber`, `Address` and... . For access to detail of each item in `statisticList` from my table:

```
foreach (var Cus in statisticList)
            {
                var allPlateDetail = (from item in Connection.DBConnection.TBStatistics
                                      where item.Customer == Cus.Customer &&
                                      item.Date >= startDate && item.Date <= endDate
                                      select item).ToList();

                //More Code...
            }
```

But It's very slow! 
I want to have `Id` of each item in `statisticList` to fast find the record in my database. Is this possible?

Or is there any way to have all of these properties in `statisticList`? like a sub list into the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I build a class:

```
public class StatisticsGroup
    {
        public IEnumerable<DB.TBStatistic> TBStatisticRecords { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

then I used this class in my query:

```
var statisticList = (from item in Connection.DBConnection.TBStatistics
                                 where item.Date >= startDate && item.Date <= endDate
                                 group item by item.Customer into grp
                                 where grp.Any()
                                 select new StatisticsGroup
                                 {
                                     Customer = grp.Key,
                                     Count = grp.Count(),
                                     TBStatisticRecords = grp.Select(p=> p)
                                 }).ToList();
```

Now I have all the detail in `TBStatisticRecords`.

Comment: you still need to replace `grp.Count() > 1` by `grp.Any()` as per Sriram answer

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim yes it's true.

Comment: why are you sticking to the " > 1" comparison?! :) .. just `where grp.Any()` without `> 1`

Comment: I just forgot to remove "> 1" :)) .

Answer (score 3):

I'm zero in Linq->Sql or EntityFramework. I'll provide some idea in terms of Linq->Objects you may try to convert this in Linq->Sql.

In first place `where grp.Count() > 1` is expensive O(n) so we use `grp.Any()` which is O(1) operation. Then we can get hold of the group which we get via `GroupBy` like this.

```
var statisticList = (from item in Connection.DBConnection.TBStatistics       
          where item.Date >= startDate && item.Date <= endDate
                     group item by item.Customer into grp
                     where grp.Any()
                     select new
                     {
                         Customer = grp.Key,
                         //Count = grp.Count(), Note I think we don't need it we can use GroupItems.Count instead
                         GroupItems = grp.ToList()
                     }).ToList();

foreach (var Cus in statisticList)
{
    //Do whatever with Cus.GroupItems
}
```

Am not sure whether this is applicable in Linq->Sql or EntityFramework, apologizes if it doesn't help. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It's return an error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DB.TBStatistic] ToList[TBStatistic](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DB.TBStatistic])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." but I'll change it to see if it's work. Thank you for your answer.